# OS X Safari - any way to debug on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, debugging, safari, cross-browser

I found out that Safari on OS X displays websites differently than it does on Windows.

However, I don't have a Mac computer to debug websites there so I want to ask if anyone doesn't have any way how to display websites on Windows like in Safari on OS X so I can debug them 
(I don't want BrowserLab or similar screenshot services, it takes ages)

I need some browser alternative that shows websites exactly as Safari does on OS X so if I would press `reload` button I immediately saw changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either get a Mac or install Mac OSX in a VM.

Comment: finally managed to install it into VirtualBox and it suits my needs. Thanks